# What's wrong with the following GNU make shell variable expansion?

Tags: shell, gcc, makefile, gnu-make, variable-expansion

On this line:

```
GCCVER:=$(shell a=`mktemp` && echo $'#include <stdio.h>\nmain() {printf("%u.%u\\n", __GNUC__, __GNUC_MINOR__);}' | gcc -o "$a" -xc -; "$a"; rm "$a")
```

I get:

```
*** unterminated call to function `shell': missing `)'.  Stop.
```

What's wrong with my stupidly circuitous variable?

### Update0

```
$ make --version
GNU Make 3.81
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.8(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
$ uname -a
Linux 2.6.38-10-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2
```

Comment: BTW, what's wrong with `$(shell gcc -v 2>&1 | tail -1 | awk '{print $$3}')` ?

Comment: @reinierpost: Nothing except that I wasn't aware of it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

when using `$` for Bash inside a Makefile, you need to double them: `$$a` for example. I'm not familiar with the notation `$'` but I'll have to assume you know what you're doing with that. unless it's a Makefile construct, you need to double the dollar sign on that one too.

also, the hash sign `#` is terminating the shell expansion in Make's evaluation, which is why it never sees the right paren. escaping it helps, but I don't have it working quite right yet.

I'm debugging it by having two steps: first is setting GCCVER to be the list of commands without the enclosing `$(shell)`, then in the 2nd step setting `GCCVER := $(shell $(GCCVER))`. you might want to try that too, commenting out the `$(shell)` step when it doesn't work, using `export`, and making a "set" recipe:

```
GCCVER := some commands here
#GCCVER := $(shell $(GCCVER))  # expand the commands, commented out now
export  # all variables available to shell
set:
        set  # make sure this is prefixed by a tab, not spaces
```

Then:

```
make set | grep GCCVER
```

[update] this works:

```
GCCVER := a=`mktemp` && echo -e '\#include <stdio.h>\nmain() {printf("%u.%u\\n", __GNUC__, __GNUC_MINOR__);}' | gcc -o "$$a" -xc -; "$$a"; rm "$$a"
GCCVER := $(shell $(GCCVER))
export
default:
    set

jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ make | grep GCCVER
GCCVER=4.6
```

And full circle, having gotten rid of the extra step:

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ make | grep GCCVER; cat Makefile 
GCCVER=4.6
GCCVER := $(shell a=`mktemp` && echo -e '\#include <stdio.h>\nmain() {printf("%u.%u\\n", __GNUC__, __GNUC_MINOR__);}' | gcc -o "$$a" -xc -; "$$a"; rm "$$a")
export
default:
    set
```

Using the `$'` Bash construct:

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ make | grep GCCVER; cat Makefile 
GCCVER=4.6
GCCVER := $(shell a=`mktemp` && echo $$'\#include <stdio.h>\nmain() {printf("%u.%u\\n", __GNUC__, __GNUC_MINOR__);}' | gcc -o "$$a" -xc -; "$$a"; rm "$$a")
export
default:
    set
```

Since your system doesn't work the same as mine, I'm going to cop out and say either use reinierpost's suggestion or, alternatively:

```
GCCVER := $(shell gcc -dumpversion | cut -d. -f1,2)
```

Comment: still testing... that's not the whole of your problem.

Comment: the -e option to echo was necessary for the \n to be interpolated.

Comment: The `$''` evaluates the contents like a C string.

Comment: OK, I'll take your word for it! But as you can see it works without it.

Comment: Great effort, but I'm getting `<stdin>:1:1: error: stray ‘#’ in program`.

Comment: what does GCCVER look like when you don't wrap $(shell) around it?

Comment: I can't seem to duplicate your error. What OS are you running? Mine is Debian stable.

Comment: I've added relevant version info to the question, here's the output of the "$" version, preshell as per your paragraph earlier on how to dump its contents: `GCCVER='a=\`mktemp\` && echo $'"'"'#include <stdio.h>\nmain() {printf("%u.%u\\n", __GNUC__, __GNUC_MINOR__);}'"'"' | gcc -o "$a" -xc -; "$a"; rm "$a"'`

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2436/discussion-between-matt-joiner-and-jcomeau-ictx)

Comment: Thanks for the comment about `#`. That saved me some time.