# Makefile - "$" not taken into account for shell command

Tags: bash, makefile, grep

I have a Makefle with the following rule

```
bash -c "find . |grep -E '\.c$|\.h$|\.cpp$|\.hpp$|Makefile' | xargs cat | wc -l"
```

I'm expecting make to run the quoted bash script and to return the number of line in my project.

Running directly the command in a terminal does the work, but it doesn't work in makefile.
If I remove `$` from the script, it does work ... but not as expected (since I only want `*.{c,cpp,h,hpp,Makefile}`.

Why `bash -c` doesn't run correctly my script?

Comment: what do you mean exactly by doesn't work

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's wrong with the following GNU make shell variable expansion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036352/whats-wrong-with-the-following-gnu-make-shell-variable-expansion)

Comment: It doesn't work because it returns 0 as result. 0 because it doesn't look at *.c file but maybe for*.c$  but "$" for grep should mean end of line

Comment: thank you Gilles. In Makefile $ should be doubled.

Answer (score 1):

if you write the rule like the following, it should produce the result you want:

```
target:
    @echo $(shell find . | grep -E '\.c$$|\.h$$|\.cpp$$|\.hpp$$|Makefile' | xargs cat | wc -l)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Makefiles, $ is used for make variables such as $(HEADERS), where HEADERS would have been defined previously using =.

To use a $ in inline bash, you have to double them to escape them. $$VAR will refer to a shell variable, and .c$$ and so on should escape the $ for the regex you're working with.

The following should suffice in escaping the $'s for what you're trying to accomplish

```
bash -c "find . |grep -E '\.c$$|\.h$$|\.cpp$$|\.hpp$$|Makefile' | xargs cat | wc -l"
```

Additionally, you can use bash globally in your Makefile as opposed to the default /bin/sh if you add this declaration:

```
SHELL = /bin/bash
```

With the above, you should be able to use the find command without needing the bash -c and quotes. The following should work if SHELL is defined as above:

```
find . |grep -E '\.c$$|\.h$$|\.cpp$$|\.hpp$$|Makefile' | xargs cat | wc -l
```

Also, note that you can, and will often see SubShells used for this purpose. These are created with (). This will make any variables defined by the inner shell local to that shell and its group of commands.